# Mutually Exclusive Geo-Spatial Markers with folium.LayerControl() in Python

Tags: python, folium

### Goal

I want to use a radio button to toggle the color and the pop-up of geo-spatial markers in a folium plot, using Python3.6 and folium version `0.9.0`. I am attempting this by creating two separate data frames that have different color values and adding them both to their own `folium.FeatureGroup()`.

### Problem

When the plot is generated, all of the radio button options just take on the last `folium.FeatureGroup()`'s values.

### Reproducible Example

Create two separate data frames with the same location names and geo-coordinates, but different categories and their own color values:

```
import pandas as pd
from branca.colormap import LinearColormap


# Create base data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({'loc_name': ['Palmdale', 'Pacoima', 'West L.A.', 'Metro L.A.', 'Lincoln Heights', 'El Monte',
                                'Pomona', 'Inglewood', 'South L.A.', 'East L.A.', 'Lynwood', 'Norwalk', 'Wilmington',
                                'Long Beach'],
                   'loc_lat': [34.5800111, 34.2662363, 34.0364075, 34.0487368, 34.0735519, 34.0733908,
                               34.0620289, 33.930828, 33.990596, 34.021968, 33.930476, 33.902052, 33.7814812,
                               33.857974],
                   'loc_lon': [-118.0915039, -118.4224082, -118.4364343, -118.3091383, -118.2161354, -118.0418393,
                               -117.7610335, -118.325139, -118.3311216, -118.164376, -118.175329, -118.083686, -118.2626444,
                               -118.185061]})


# Create df1 and its variable coloring, based on its values
# ------------------------------------------------
df1 = df.copy()
df1['category'] = 'volume'
df1['value'] = [23148, 78629, 38670, 176483, 136961, 64221, 29217, 
                131525, 172852, 113231, 144485, 63213, 51900, 88446]

df1_colormap = LinearColormap(colors=['blue', 'red'], 
                              vmin=df1['value'].min(), 
                              vmax=df1['value'].max())

def df1_color_tag(row):
    return df1_colormap(row['value'])

df1['color'] = df1.apply(df1_color_tag, axis=1)


# Create df2 and its variable coloring, based on its values
# ------------------------------------------------
df2 = df.copy()
df2['category'] = 'index'
df2['value'] = range(1, 15)

df2_colormap = LinearColormap(colors=['green', 'yellow'], 
                              vmin=df2['value'].min(), 
                              vmax=df2['value'].max())

def df2_color_tag(row):
    return df2_colormap(row['value'])

df2['color'] = df2.apply(df2_color_tag, axis=1)
```

Create a `folium` plot, setting `df1` and `df2` values in `folium.FeatureGroups()`:

```
import folium
from folium import plugins


# Create a map
la_map = folium.Map(location=[34.24, -118.091233], zoom_start=9) 

category_feature_groups = {}


# Create category feature group markers for df1 dataframe
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
feature_group_df1 = folium.FeatureGroup(name='volume', overlay=False)
folium.TileLayer(tiles='OpenStreetMap').add_to(feature_group_df1)
feature_group_df1.add_to(la_map)
    
#Loop through each row of crc data to plot CRC location markers
for i,row in df1.iterrows():
    
    custom_icon = folium.DivIcon(
        icon_size=(40, 40),
        icon_anchor=(20, 20),  # Position of the icon center
        html=f"""
        <div style="width: 40px; 
                    height: 40px; 
                    background-color: {row['color']}; 
                    border-radius: 50%; 
                    display: flex; 
                    justify-content: center; 
                    align-items: center; 
                    color: white; 
                    font-weight: bold;">
        </div>
        """
    )
    
    #Setup the content of the popup
    iframe = folium.IFrame(row['loc_name'] + '<br/><br/>' + \
                           row['category'] + ': ' + str(row['value']))
    
    #Initialise the popup using the iframe
    popup = folium.Popup(iframe, min_width=200, max_width=200)
    
    #Add each row to the map
    folium.Marker(location=[row['loc_lat'],row['loc_lon']],
                  popup = popup,
                  icon = custom_icon).add_to(la_map)
    
feature_group_df1.add_to(la_map)
category_feature_groups['volume'] = feature_group_df1


# Create category feature group markers for df2 dataframe
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
feature_group_df2 = folium.FeatureGroup(name='index', overlay=False)
folium.TileLayer(tiles='OpenStreetMap').add_to(feature_group_df2)
feature_group_df2.add_to(la_map)
    
#Loop through each row of crc data to plot CRC location markers
for i,row in df2.iterrows():
    
    custom_icon = folium.DivIcon(
        icon_size=(40, 40),
        icon_anchor=(20, 20),  # Position of the icon center
        html=f"""
        <div style="width: 40px; 
                    height: 40px; 
                    background-color: {row['color']}; 
                    border-radius: 50%; 
                    display: flex; 
                    justify-content: center; 
                    align-items: center; 
                    color: white; 
                    font-weight: bold;">
        </div>
        """
    )
    
    #Setup the content of the popup
    iframe = folium.IFrame(row['loc_name'] + '<br/><br/>' + \
                           row['category'] + ': ' + str(row['value']))
    
    #Initialise the popup using the iframe
    popup = folium.Popup(iframe, min_width=200, max_width=200)
    
    #Add each row to the map
    folium.Marker(location=[row['loc_lat'],row['loc_lon']],
                  popup = popup,
                  icon = custom_icon).add_to(la_map)
    
feature_group_df2.add_to(la_map)
category_feature_groups['index'] = feature_group_df2


# Add Layer Control
folium.LayerControl(collapsed=False, overlay=True).add_to(la_map)

la_map
```

The problem is that the output displays the `df2` (i.e., last defined `folium.FeatureGroup()`) values for each of the radio button selections:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While I did not understand your code in its entirety (it needs a tldr/ needs to be minimal), from what I understand is that you need layer control for your dataframes and a way to toggle between layers (radio button).

To do this one option is using `geopandas.explore()`. See below code that uses `df1` and `df2` as per your first code block:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

# Convert your pandas dataframes to geopandas dataframes
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df1['loc_lon'], df1['loc_lat'])]
gdf_1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df1, geometry=geometry, crs='EPSG:4326')

geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df2['loc_lon'], df2['loc_lat'])]
gdf_2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df2, geometry=geometry, crs='EPSG:4326')

# add your map viz here
m = gdf_1.explore('color',name='volume', 
                  tiles='cartodbpositron', 
                  tooltip = ['loc_name'],
                  marker_type = 'circle_marker', marker_kwds = {'radius': 40})
m = gdf_2.explore('color',name='index', m=m)

folium.TileLayer("Open Street Map", show=True).add_to(m)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)  # use folium to add layer control
m  # show map
```

You can change the `marker_kwds` and `tooltip` based on your requirements (I added some basic values there; google for your exact usecases).

Hopefully, this helps you.

See output below:

1. all layers selected:
   [image]
2. Only index layer selected:
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. What version of `geopandas` are you using? I'm working with version `0.9.0`, and I'm getting `AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'explore'`.

Comment: geopandas 0.14.0